# Should I be concerned if my dog swallowed a battery?

Tags: dogs, safety, eating, poison, digestion

My dog may have swallowed the battery off his invisible fence collar. How concerned should I be? The battery is the flat, round type that is roughly the size of a quarter ([button cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_cell)).

---

Update: the battery was found, so he did not swallow it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This is a medical emergency!

A vet must make an x-ray of the stomach **as soon as possible** to verify whether or not the dog actually swallowed the battery. If he did indeed, the battery must be removed **as soon as possible** by a means the vet chooses. If the battery is intact, vomitting might be the easiest solution, but if the battery is punctured, it may cause even more damaged if vomitting is induced.

The stomach acid corrodes the outer layer of the battery, which then releases it's toxic chemicals into the stomach. That can cause chemical burns and tissue death anywhere from the mouth, to the esophagus, intestines and anus. Even if the battery wasn't punctured and passed through the stomach intact, it may still block the intestine and cause an incredibly painful intestinal obstruction that is lethal if untreated.

You should watch out for symptoms like:

- reluctance to eat or drink
- drooling
- red or grey spots in the dogs mouth
- bad breath
- vomitting
- diarrhea
- lethargy

As a **first aid measure** you should feed your dog a very bland diet of plain cooked chicken, rice or pasta (without added salt) and offer them some milk or cottage cheese.

For more information please read:

[What should I do if my dog eats a battery?](https://www.aecmemphis.com/site/vet-blog-memphis/2019/11/14/dog-ate-battery) by Animal Emergency Center
[The Dangers of Batteries and Your Pets: What You Should Know](https://www.aspca.org/news/dangers-batteries-and-your-pets-what-you-should-know) by the American Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals (ASPCA)
[Dogs & Batteries – More Dangerous Than You Might Think](https://www.preventivevet.com/dogs/dogs-and-the-dangers-of-swallowing-batteries) by Preventive Vet

Comment: Meant to follow up earlier, but the battery was found, so he did not swallow it

Answer (score 0):

Following up with what Elmy said, I would also recommend monitoring your pet after the battery is removed to see if they have any other suspicious symptoms. If you want to better prevent battery swallowing, get bitter tasting batteries. They sell them and they work great.

Comment: Your vet may also recommend some after treatments if the battery was punctured but removed before permenant damage was done.

Comment: This is a specialized battery for this collar.  I doubt I can find one that is bitter.  Plus, my dog eats everything, I doubt it would discourage him

Comment: Is it a 3V? If so, there are child proof batteries however i doubt that it will work on pets. My recommendation is to find the best thing your dog hates taste wise that's nontoxic,  if you cant, then duct tape over the collar might be the best option.

Comment: If you can, then try and cover the battery in it and put the battery in the collar

Comment: https://www.chewy.com/petsafe-rfa-67-6-volt-replacement/dp/48619

Comment: @Kevin Its most likely a 3V but that might work too